# EXT JS 5/Spring MVC : How to bind ext js form to java object with spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc, extjs

I want to bind me ext js form with an object Java.

For now I can just bind each field individually like that :

My Form :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.login.Login', {
    extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
    alias: 'widget.login',

    requires : ['Ext.form.Panel', 'Ext.layout.container.Fit'],

    autoShow: true,
    height: 200,
    width: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    iconCls: 'key',
    title: "Login",
    closeAction: 'hide',
    closable: false,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'form',
            frame: false,
            bodyPadding: 15,
            layout: 'anchor',
            defaults: {
                anchor: '100%',
                labelWidth: 100
            },

            defaultType: 'textfield',
            items: [
                {
                    name: 'user',
                    fieldLabel: "Login ",
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'under',
                    emptyText: 'Login',
                    maxLength: 25
                },
                {
                    inputType: 'password',
                    name: 'password',
                    fieldLabel: "Password",
                    emptyText:'Password',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    msgTarget: 'under',
                    maxLength: 15,
                    enableKeyEvents: true,
                    id: 'login-password'
                }
            ],

            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'tbfill'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            itemId: 'cancel',
                            text: 'Cancel'
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'button',
                            itemId: 'submit',
                            formBind: true,
                            text: "Submit"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

A part of my submit method :

```
     loginForm.submit({
        method : 'POST',
        url: '/myapp/login/login.sp',
        success: function(form, action) {
            Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
        },
        failure: function(form, action) {
            switch (action.failureType) {
                case Ext.form.action.Action.CLIENT_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Form fields may not be submitted with invalid values');
                break;
                case Ext.form.action.Action.CONNECT_FAILURE:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', 'Ajax communication failed');
                break;
                case Ext.form.action.Action.SERVER_INVALID:
                Ext.Msg.alert('Failure', action.result.msg);
            }
        }

    });
```

My method of my Java Controller for login :

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public void checkConnection(@RequestParam(value="user", required = true) String user, @RequestParam(value="password", required = true) String password) {
    logger.info("LOGIN !!!");
}
```

And I want something like this :

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public void checkConnection(@Annotation LoginModel) {
    logger.info("LOGIN !!!");
}
```

And my LoginModel would be like this :

```
public class LoginModel {

    /** User */
    private String user;

    /** Password */
    private String password;

}
```

regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `@ModelAttribute` is what you need. It tells Spring to retrieve the parameters from the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value="login/login", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public void checkConnection(@ModelAttribute LoginModel loginModel) {
    logger.info("LOGIN !!!");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. I tried it many times and it did not work and now it works ... sorry for the inconvenience.